# UnicodeDecodeError: unexpected end of data

Tags: unicode, python-3.x

I have a huge text file which I want to open.
I'm reading the file in chunks, avoiding memory issues related to reading too much of the file all at once.

**code snippet:**

```
def open_delimited(fileName, args):

    with open(fileName, args, encoding="UTF16") as infile:
        chunksize = 10000
        remainder = ''
        for chunk in iter(lambda: infile.read(chunksize), ''):
            pieces = re.findall(r"(\d+)\s+(\d+_\d+)", remainder + chunk)
            for piece in pieces[:-1]:
                yield piece
            remainder = '{} {} '.format(*pieces[-1]) 
        if remainder:
            yield remainder
```

the code throws the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode bytes in position 8190-8191: unexpected end of data`.

I tried `UTF8` and got the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`.

`latin-1` and `iso-8859-1` raised the error `IndexError: list index out of range`

A sample of the input file:

```
b'\xff\xfe1\x000\x000\x005\x009\x00\t\x001\x000\x000\x005\x009\x00_\x009\x007\x004\x007\x001\x007\x005\x003\x001\x000\x009\x001\x00\t\x00\t\x00P\x00o\x00s\x00t\x00\t\x001\x00\t\x00H\x00a\x00p\x00p\x00y\x00 \x00B\x00i\x00r\x00t\x00h\x00d\x00a\x00y\x00\t\x002\x000\x001\x001\x00-\x000\x008\x00-\x002\x004\x00 \x00'
```

I will also mention that I have several of those huge text files.
`UTF16` works fine for many of them, and fail at a specific file.

Anyway to resolve this issue?

Comment: If your inputfile *is* UTF-16 (albeit truncated), then Latin1 or UTF-8 will certainly not work.

Comment: Can we see a sample of your inputfile? Then at least we can take a stab at guessing the encoding used. Read the file as binary, and print that. `print(open(fileName, 'rb').read(120))` should give us enough to work with.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I added a sample of the input file.

Comment: That is most definitely UTF16. If that data is corrupted somewhere, there is little we can do to fix that. You *could* try a different chunk size, perhaps there is a bug in `TextIOWrapper.read()` where a it ends up with a partial read of a surrogate pair. I recommend a power of 2. `16384` is 2**14, for example.

Comment: In any case, trying to use any other codec is not going to work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried `16384`. It didn't work. I can accept a solution were parts that are corrupted in data will be ignored. What will be a good way to do so?

Comment: That is going to be *hard*. You'd have to detect exactly what offset in the file that would be, bypass the buffer, seek, clear the buffer, then read again. The offset should be calculable from how much you've read so far plus the offset named in the exception.

Comment: Even then, you'd still have to deal with the fact your data file is corrupted in at least one location. How many more corrupted bytes will be present? Is the data recovable *at all*?

Comment: The alternative is to ignore errors altogether by setting `errors='ignore'` on the `open()` call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To ignore corrupted data (which can lead to data loss), set `errors='ignore'` on the `open()` call:

```
with open(fileName, args, encoding="UTF16", errors='ignore') as infile:
```

The [`open()` function documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) states:

> - `'ignore'` ignores errors. Note that ignoring encoding errors can lead to data loss.

This does not mean you can recover from the apparent data corruption you are experiencing.

To illustrate, imagine a byte was dropped or added somewhere in your file. UTF-16 is a codec that uses 2 bytes per character. If there is one byte missing or surplus then all byte-pairs following the missing or extra byte are going to be out of alignment.

That can lead to problems decoding further down the line, not necessarily immediately. There are some codepoints in UTF-16 that are illegal, but usually because they are used in combination with another byte-pair; your exception was thrown for such an invalid codepoint. But there may have been hundreds or thousands byte-pairs preceding that point that were valid UTF-16, if not legible text.

Comment: I tried the `errors='ignore'` and get `remainder = '{} {} '.format(*pieces[-1]) 
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Right, because now you are apparently ending up with a chunk where `re.findall()` returns *no matches at all*. That is the risk of ignoring invalid characters; if *one* byte is missing in your file, then the UTF-16 decoding may be unreadable now; it is effectively not detectable *what* byte is missing in that case and the exception you saw could be well past the file corruption.

Answer (score 4):

I was doing the same thing (reading many large text files in chunks) and ran into the same error with one the files:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wordcount.py", line 128, in <module>
    decodedtext = rawtext.decode('utf8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 9999999: unexpected end of data
```

Here's what I found: the problem was a particular Unicode sequence (`\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0`) spanning two chunks. Thus that sequence was split and became undecodable. Here's how I solved it:

```
# read text
rawtext = file.read(chunksize)

# fix splited end
if chunknumber < totalchunks:
    while rawtext[-1] != ' ':
        rawtext = rawtext + file.read(1)

# decode text
decodedtext = rawtext.decode('utf8')
```

This also solves the more general problem of words being cut in half when they span two chunks.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen in Python 3 when you read/write a `io.StringIO` object instead of `io.BytesIO`