# What's the cause of this UnicodeDecodeError with an nvarchar field using pyodbc and MSSQL?

Tags: python, sql-server, unicode, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I can read from a MSSQL database by sending queries in python through pypyodbc.

Mostly unicode characters are handled correctly, but I've hit a certain character that causes an error.

The field in question is of type `nvarchar(50)` and begins with this character "" which renders for me a bit like this...

```
-----
|100|
|111| 
-----
```

If that number is hex `0x100111` then it's the character `supplementary private use area-b u+100111`. Though interestingly, if it's binary `0b100111` then it's an apostrophe, could it be that the wrong encoding was used when the data was uploaded? This field is storing part of a Chinese postal address.

The error message includes

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: unexpected end of data

Here it is in full...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "question.py", line 19, in <module>
    results.fetchone()   File "/VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT_DIR/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 1869, in fetchone
    value_list.append(buf_cvt_func(from_buffer_u(alloc_buffer)))   File "/VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT_DIR/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 482, in UCS_dec
    uchar = buffer.raw[i:i + ucs_length].decode(odbc_decoding)   File "/VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT_DIR/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_16.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_16_decode(input, errors, True) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: unexpected end of data
```

Here's some minimal reproducing code...

```
import pypyodbc

connection_string = (
    "DSN=sqlserverdatasource;"
    "UID=REDACTED;"
    "PWD=REDACTED;"
    "DATABASE=obi_load")

connection = pypyodbc.connect(connection_string)

cursor = connection.cursor()

query_sql = (
    "SELECT address_line_1 "
    "FROM address "
    "WHERE address_id == 'REDACTED' ")

with cursor.execute(query_sql) as results:
    row = results.fetchone() # This is the line that raises the error.
    print row
```

Here is a chunk of my `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`

```
[global]
;   tds version = 4.2
;   dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;   debug flags = 0xffff
;   timeout = 10
;   connect timeout = 10
    text size = 64512

[sqlserver]
host = REDACTED
port = 1433
tds version = 7.0
client charset = UTF-8
```

I've also tried with `client charset = UTF-16` and omitting that line all together.

Here's the relevant chunk from my `/etc/odbc.ini`

```
[sqlserverdatasource]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = ODBC connection via FreeTDS
Trace = No
Servername = sqlserver
Database = REDACTED
```

Here's the relevant chunk from my `/etc/odbcinst.ini`

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = TDS Driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
CPTimeout =
CPReuse =
UsageCount = 1
```

I can work around this issue by fetching results in a try/except block, throwing away any rows that raise a `UnicodeDecodeError`, but is there a solution? Can I throw away just the undecodable character, or is there a way to fetch this line without raising an error?

It's not inconceivable that some bad data has ended up on the database.

I've Googled around and checked this site's related questions, but have had no luck.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357675/unicodedecodeerror-unexpected-end-of-data?

Comment: What do you get if you `SELECT master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CONVERT(VARBINARY, [address_line_1])) AS foo FROM [address] ...` ? That should show you exactly what is at the beginning of the text value.

Comment: @GordThompson 0x4700520045004e00410044004a00c400520047004100540041004e002000

Comment: Interesting. Those are definitely valid NVARCHAR bytes (UTF-16LE)  but they represent 'GRENADJÄRGATAN ' which doesn't look particularly Chinese to me. Still, that's what pyodbc should return.

Comment: @GordThompson My apologies, that was from the previous line.

Comment: @GordThompson 0xc0db11dd53004300490045004e0043004500260054004500430048004e00

Comment: You're right, that first character (four bytes) is U+100111. Unfortunately, I am unable to recreate your issue under Python 2.7.11 with pyodbc 3.0.7. When I `print(row)` I get `(u'\U00100111SCIENCE&TECHN', )`. However, I'm using Windows and the "SQL Server Native Client 10.0" ODBC driver. Still, it does suggest that it's not a problem with Python or pyodbc *per se*. Are you using reasonably current versions of Python 2.7, pyodbc, and FreeTDS?

Comment: ...also, just tried with pypyodbc 1.3.3 and that worked okay, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was eventually worked around, I suspect that the problem was that text had a character of one encoding hammered into a field with another declared encoding through some hacky method when the table was being set up.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue myself by using this:

```
conn.setencoding('utf-8')
```

immediately before creating a cursor.

Where `conn` is the connection object.

I was fetching tens of millions of rows with `fetchall()`, and in the middle of a transaction that would be extremely expensive to undo manually, so I couldn't afford to simply skip invalid ones.

Source where I found the solution: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/112#issuecomment-264734456

Comment: Interesting, but MSSQL uses UTF-16LE, which pyodbc also uses by default, so I wouldn't expect specifying UTF-8 to help under normal circumstances. Still, if it seems to have helped you then it might help others who really do have UTF-8 stuffed into an MSSQL database.

Comment: I am using Azure SQL, which may have a few quirks that make it different? Either way, I find it bizarre, since the only way data gets into that database is through the same codebase/`pyodbc` driver that I was using to fetch the data.